# Putting validation in delivery note in migo transaction ( SAP-ABAP)

Tags: abap, sap-erp

So the scenario is when a user enter a value in delivery note number then it must go through the validation which I need to put on.

[image]

Validation = delivery note input character should not be greater than 10.

I know the BAdI name as well: `MB_MIGO_BADI`.

Question is how to approach that?

And how to write the code?

Can you guys help me with that.

Comment: Create new implementation and try to use CHECK_HEADER method. Then you can show the error message. 
There are many source for this topic. Check them out to see all solutions provided by other people.
For example: https://community.sap.com/t5/application-development-discussions/validate-migo-screen-field-goods-recipient-value-with-custom-table-entry/m-p/8488138